# Рow to get 2 to 4 of the object element

Tags: c#, linq

I had error from line

```
Dictionary<int, string> viewBusinesAndCountLeft = grptemp.Take(4).ToDictionary(x => x.Count, x => x.BusinessCategoryName);
```

error: "The element with the same key has already been added."

How to do this?

```
var grptemp = (from adsBusines in m_adsRepository.SaleBusinesAds
               group adsBusines by adsBusines.BusinessCategory.Name
               into grp
               select new
               {
                  BusinessCategoryName = grp.Key,
                  Count = grp.Select(x => x.BusinessCategory.ChildItems.Count()).Distinct().Count()
               }).Take(8);

Dictionary<int, string> viewBusinesAndCountLeft = grptemp.Take(4).ToDictionary(x => x.Count, x => x.BusinessCategoryName);
Dictionary<int, string> viewBusinesAndCountRigth = grptemp.Skip(4).Take(4).ToDictionary(x => x.Count, x => x.BusinessCategoryName);
```

Comment: 2 different categories could have same count so the error is a normal, even you set distinct you recall count after it

Comment: Your code gives you a .Count of distinct .Count values. This is strange, are you sure this is what you are wanting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the count as the key for the dictionary which means you will throw that exception whenever you happen to find two categories with the same count.

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you should have the 'business category' as the key to the dictionary and the count as the value.

E.g.

```
Dictionary<string, int> viewBusinesAndCountLeft = grptemp.Take(4).ToDictionary(x => x.BusinessCategoryName, x => x.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a `Dictionary<T,U>` means a dictionary with key of type T (in this case, `int`) - and the key in a dictionary must be unique.

You probably want the key to be the string, and the value to be the count. Try switching your arguments:

```
Dictionary<string, int> viewBusinesAndCountLeft = 
    grptemp.Take(4).ToDictionary(x => x.BusinessCategoryName, x => x.Count);
```